# jQuery selector choice to access DOM elements

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following table. I would like to check, whether certain rows and columns (col) exist or not. Before I was working with ids and that was fast enough, but now I use the DOM directly with index() in jQuery and no ids. But it is definitely slower! Here is my table:

```
**************************************************
* line * col * col * col * col * col *           *
* line * col * col *                             *
* line * col * col * col * col * col * col * col *
* line * col * col * col *                       *
* line * col * col * col * col * col *           *
* line * col * col * col * col * col *           *
* ...  * ... * ... * ... * ... * ... * ... * ... *
**************************************************
```

In the table you can see the class names of the table cells. The  tags have a class called "row". The col count can vary. I need a script to check / access these rows and columns. I have the following script:

```
function isRow( r ) {
    var row = $( ".row" ).eq(r);
    return ( typeof row != "undefined" ? true : false );
}
function getRow( r ) {
    var row = $( ".row" ).eq(r);
    return ( typeof row == "undefined" ? null : row );
}
function isCell( r, c ) {
    var col = $( ".row" ).eq(r).children(".col").get(c);
    return ( typeof col == "undefined" ? true : false );
}
function getCell( r, c ) {
    var col = $( ".row" ).eq(r).children(".col").eq(c);
    return ( typeof col == "undefined" ? null : col );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a faster way to access the DOM elements? There is probably a better selector, but I don't know how to rewrite my code.

Any idea?

Bernhard

Comment: Do you need it to be checked dynamically? Because you could store a copy of the $(".row") selector in a local variable and work with that. That'd be faster for sure.

Comment: Use `find` instead of `children`, it's ~10% quicker: http://jsperf.com/jquery-children-vs-find/54

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try find. Dynamically? Yes, I think so. It will change often. Adding and deleting rows and cols. I just have to find the right selector. When I loop through the whole set, then it slows down considerably. I will try "each" to loop through.

Comment: OK. I haven't finished yet, but I think I know the problem. The looping through the whole table takes too long because I access every single col with a new selector. But the each method will shorten the access to the whole table. I'm sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unbelievable. I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with the jQuery selectors at all. It was a "rogue" event handler combined with a setTimeout that put the script into a deadly loop. And it seems I didn't try that with the old code. Sorry to have bothered you all. :)

But I found that at times Javascript is easier and faster than jQuery. So the points go to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is that much of an issue you are better off with a plain JS for/ while loop, and as much variable caching as possible, eg:

```
// returns an array with a data obj about each cell, with following format:
// { row: x, col: y } + any properties added by the function passed as param
// @param {element} table - The table element you want to loop
// @param {function} fn - The function to execute on each cell, with parameter (cell)
function loopTableCells(table, fn) {
  var rows = table.children, // note: native children prop is faster than jQuery
      len = table.children.length, cell, cellArr = [], cellCount, cellData;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cell = rows[i].firstChild;
    cellCount = 0;
    if (cell) { // in case the row has no children, do nothing
      do { // it has at least one child, so do at least once
        cellData = fn(cell);
        cellData.row = i; // store the table row index
        cellData.col = cellCount;
        cellArr.push(cellData);
        cellCount++;
        cell = rows[i].nextSibling;
      } while (rows[i].nextSibling);
    }
  }
  return cellArr;
}
```

You could then use this function like so:

```
function getCellData(cell) { // store any cell property you want in obj
  var obj = {};
  obj.hasChildren = (cell.firstElementChild ? true : false);
  obj.hasText = (cell.textContent ? true : false);
  obj.element = cell;
  if (cell.id) obj.id = cell.id;
  if (cell.className) obj.class = cell.className;
  return obj; 
}

var tableData = loopTableCells($('#myTable'), getCellData);
```

Now you have a flat array of table cells, you can simply iterate over them, for example the (pointless) function beneath removes all table cells which have an uneven index in the table row. :)

```
$.each(tableData, function(i, val) {
  if (val.col/2 !== parseInt(val.col/2)) 
    $(val.element).remove();
}
```